# Whether the .so and .jar files should be built by myself on Android?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have trained my own modles by Tensorflow ,and download the android samples run on Android.I only change the .pb and .txt files .BUT it crash on Android and give a error :

```
**E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate()**
```

Anyone can help me ?
And i want to know whether i should build my own .jar and .so files in Android Studio by Bazel?

Thanks very much

Comment: What changes do you make to the .pb and .txt files? Does everything work without your changes?

Comment: I only move my own .pb and .txt to the assets. And change the private static final String MODEL_FILE and LABEL_FILE in ClassifierActivity.java.

Comment: I have optimized my pb by use bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference

Comment: Does the example work with the default pb and txt files, or is that also broken?

Comment: The example run well with its original .pb and .txt files. But i use my own .pb and .txt  instead of original files,the app crash. I have no idea.....thx you help me!

Comment: Probably you're generating the .pb and .txt files somehow wrong, then?